# Resolving circular imports of Python type hints

Tags: python, circular-dependency, mypy, python-typing

I have to Python classes that have instances of each other as properties

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B) -> None:
        self.b = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A) -> None:
        self.a = a
```

This works fine if those classes are defined in the same file, but in my case they're both quite large and I would like to move them to separate files. However if I do this I would I have to import `B` into `a.py` and `A` into `b.py`, which will cause a circular import error. Does anyone know of a patter that I can use to have `A` and `B` in separate files, maintain type hinting, and run into a circular import error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [Python ignores type hints in quotes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#runtime-or-type-checking):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, b: 'B') -> None:
        self.b = a
```

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a: 'A') -> None:
        self.a = a
```